# Single Jar for multiple aws lambda functions developed using JAVA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, executable-jar

I want to make a single jar file for some lambda functions. I have seen many blogs and articles where different handleRequest methods are used as events.
How this will be mapped to aws lambda function as pakage.classname:handleReq() is defined on aws console.
Confused about its implementation.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have multiple functions inside a single jar , for each function this entire jar will be uploaded.

It is required to define for each of the functions the handler class.

If you use cloudformation it will look something like:

```yaml
FirstLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: first-function
      Description: "Your first function"
      Handler: com.app.functions.FirstFunction
      Runtime: java11
      CodeUri: ./build/libs/all-functions.jar

SecondLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: second-function
      Description: "Your second function"
      Handler: com.functions.SecondFunction
      Runtime: java11
      CodeUri: ./build/libs/all-functions.jar
   
....
```

If you do it manually it is required to upload the jar in S3 and once you create the function from AWS console to point out to this jar and write down the expected handler.

Note: Usually you could do this if all functions are really very closely related to each other, otherwise it is better to split them in separate jars.